# Solve for x Given Two Square Roots: Algebra Problem

Tags: radicals

I am trying to solve for all real numbers for $x$ given $5=\sqrt{9-x^2}+\sqrt{16-x^2}$.

The answer is that $x=\pm \frac{12}{5}$. I am looking for a clean way to do it. I am stumped, and I feel like I am missing something about conjugates here.

Comment: What have you tried? Squaring once, then rearranging and squaring again?

Comment: Whoops! That will work!!!!

Comment: @DietrichBurde I got it from there. Thank you for your help!

Comment: hello is my answer helpful @W.G.

Comment: I think it's clean. Just square it a couple of times. I kept thinking about how to do it one move. Thank you as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no clean way that I know of. We have

$5=\sqrt{9-x^2}+\sqrt{16-x^2} \implies $

$5-\sqrt{9-x^2}=\sqrt{16-x^2} \implies $

$(5-\sqrt{9-x^2})^2=16-x^2 \implies $

$25+9-x^2-10\sqrt{9-x^2} = 16-x^2 \implies $

$34-x^2-10\sqrt{9-x^2}  = 16-x^2 \implies $

$18 =10\sqrt{9-x^2} \implies $

$\frac{9}{5} = \sqrt{9-x^2} \implies $

$\frac{81}{25} = 9-x^2 \implies $

$ \frac{-144}{25} = -x^2  \implies $

$ x = \pm \frac{12}{5} $